# SQL: set existing column as Primary Key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, primary-key

I have a database with 3 columns:

```
id, name, somethingelse
```

This table has no index set and i am getting "No index defined!" in phpmyadmin
id is a 7digit alphanumeric value, unique to each row.
I want to set Drugid to be the primarykey/index (i dont know the difference if there is one)
Please explain in detail as i am new to this.
Thank you.

Comment: What DB engine are you using?

Comment: mysql i guess, he said he is using phpmyadmin

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Either run in SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)           ---or Drugid, whichever you want it to be PK
```

or use the PHPMyAdmin interface (Table Structure)

Answer (score 6):

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD PRIMARY KEY (Drugid);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it with phpmyadmin interface:

Select the table -> Go to structure tab -> On the row corresponding to the column you want, click on the icon with a key

Answer (score 3):

```
alter table table_name
add constraint myprimarykey primary key(column);
```

reference : 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp

Answer (score 0):

Go to localhost/phpmyadmin and press enter key. Now select:

```
database --> table_name --->Structure --->Action  ---> Primary -->click on Primary
```