# Adding Unique primary key to table with 100,000 redundant records

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-key-relationship

I have a database that has over 100,000 records of users and has no primary key. Could you explain to me how I would accomplish the following:
1. Auto generate primary keys based on Firstname MiddleName LastName. 
2. Note that some records are redundant ie same users and I want the same users to have the same primary key e.g Mary Jane Joe is appearing 20 times in the rows I would want her to have the same primary key in all appearances.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not delete duplicates, then add an auto increment `int` key?

Comment: Then it's not a primary key

Comment: @Bohemian...how do I delete the duplicates as it's a large database??

Comment: you can create a composite unique key/ primary key with the OPTION IGNORE then MySQL deletes all duplicates

Comment: Are rows "redundant" based just on the name?  Or on _all_ columns of the rows?

Comment: Do the redundant rows violate entity integrity, or are they different entity instances that only look the same?

Answer (score 0):

### Best Option

Use a truly unique primary key by adding a not null int field with auto-increment. This will automatically give each record a unique primary key. If you still want to use the fields described above as a unique field, I would add a composite unique key between the fields.

One of the main benefits of this is that integer fields are a lot faster to query than varchars. That being said, your table only has 100,000 records so it will be negligible at this time.

### Alternate

If you still want to use the keys you defined, then you have a few options both with the same process.

1. Add a regular, nullable varchar field to your table, not a primary key yet([like this](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-add-column/))
2. Find duplicates and delete them
3. Loop through each record and create your primary key based on the values you described and update the current records field defined in step 1 with the key.
4. Alter the table to now add your primary key ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702766/sql-set-existing-column-as-primary-key-in-mysql))

I do have to caution you though, it sounds like your idea of a primary key is not truly unique, which defeats the purpose of a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Build the new table with the auto-inc (if needed) and the uniqueness constraint on name:

```
CREATE TABLE new (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    UNIQUE(Firstname, MiddleName, LastName)
);
```

Copy all non-dup rows into that table.  (This assumes "dup" involves just the 3 columns, not just the name.)

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO new
                   (Firstname MiddleName LastName, ...)
    SELECT DISTINCT Firstname MiddleName LastName, ...
        FROM real;
```

Switch tables (if desired):

```
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;
DROP TABLE old;
```